# Is a website block not visible on Safari on MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, safari

A client of mine claims he cannot see the social icons (on the left side of the screen) when viewing the website on Macbook Pro with Safari. Those icons are perfectly visible on all devices I've tested it with.

Are there any Macbook Pro users that can confirm the bug? The website URL is as follows:

https://www.mydaypix.com

Comment: Not a site for opinions, but I will test it. – A good site for opinions is the Reddit for Macbooks > https://www.reddit.com/r/macbook/

Comment: Tested, I can see the buttons, however clicking results in nothing happening.

Comment: @Deka87 The link is broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd get him to check AdBlock…
Safari prefs > Extensions > AdBlock >'Click me to show AdBlock's options…

**Other Filter lists**
☐ Antisocial filter list (removes social media buttons)

Comment: That's a good point! I will have to ask him.

Comment: You were absolutely right! I would never think about that!